# what does +p mean when written to /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I've activated logs for wireguard, effectively I want to disable them now - first, the journey takes me to understanding what was added, therefore this question here.

I activated the logs with this cmd:
`# modprobe wireguard && echo module wireguard +p > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`

I want to understand what was added to the file. When running `echo module wireguard +p` I don't get any results, `echo`s manpage doesn't list information about this `+p` thingy.

could you please enlighten me, what `+p` does?

Comment: This is something that the [first hit in a google search](https://gist.github.com/artizirk/5bc87e345f850a8a0724929e0436ef84) for your command is likely to answer. Furthermore, it's not about managing business IT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the `+p` is a kernel debug directive where `+` adds the given flag to the configuration and the given flag `p` in this case will enable the pr_debug() callsite. The echo command simply writes to the dynamic debug configuration file at `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`. For a more detailed explanation [Dynamic Debug - The Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html).

Comment: So basically `-p` disables dynamic debugging.

Comment: @W.M. Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I know one user already gave the link to the kernel doc, but for the lazy one, there are others flags beside the `p`.

The flags are (from kernel docs):

```
p    enables the pr_debug() callsite.
f    Include the function name in the printed message
l    Include line number in the printed message
m    Include module name in the printed message
t    Include thread ID in messages not generated from interrupt context
```

So to enable them from the question above do `echo module wireguard +pfm > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`.

To remove them just do `echo module wireguard -pfm > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`.